# Unable to Execute Remote Process

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

I am trying to run a few commands on a remote machine using `Win32_Process`, but I can't get it to work.

This is what I tried first:

```
var processClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\server.domain.co.uk\root\cimv2:Win32_Process");

var inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = @"echo. 2>C:\users\user.name\desktop\EmptyFile.txt";
inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"C:\windows\system32";

var outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

But nothing happens. I also tried running this locally at `root\cimv2:Win32_Process`, but again there was no effect. I was able to get it working locally when calling `notepad.exe` instead of the command line, but this does not work on the remote computer.

How can I work out what is going wrong with this?

In `outParams`, which is a `System.Management.ManagementBaseObject`,  I can see that `ClassPath` contains the value `Evaluation timed out` - could this be a clue as to why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading around this and running some tests, it seems that similar to those started from `CScript`, [these processes cannot be made interactive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> You can use Win32_Process.Create to execute a script or application on a remote computer. However, for security reasons, **the process cannot be interactive**. When Win32_Process.Create is called on the local computer, the process can be interactive.

I am still a bit confused, because the code I ran above did not appear in the task manager, yet the article goes on to say:

> The remote process has no user interface but it **is listed in the Task Manager**

Either way, this suits my needs as I am running a shell command - however it is worth noting that executing cmd commands in this way requires that they are formatted as:

```
cmd /c <command-goes-here>
```

In my case, the command needs to be run from a specific location, so I need to pass:

```
cmd /c cd <path-to-executable> && <command-goes-here>
```